# Hide x-Axis from angularjs-chartjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, chart.js

I am using angularjs-chartjs to display charts. How can I hide the x-axis without actually setting labels : ["", "", ""]

I only wish to hide them as I will be needing to use them inside my toolTipTemplate

```
 vm.att = {
            labels: avgLabels,
            datasets: [
              {
                  label: "Average Response Time",
                  fillColor: Colors.byName('warning'),
                  strokeColor: Colors.byName('warning'),
                  highlightFill: Colors.byName('warning'),
                  highlightStroke: Colors.byName('warning'),
                  data: avgTest
              },
            ]
        };

        vm.barOptions = {

            scaleLabel: "<%=value%>" + ' ' + 'ms',
            scaleBeginAtZero: true,
            scaleShowGridLines: false,
            scaleGridLineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.05)',
            scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
            barShowStroke: true,
            barStrokeWidth: 2,
            barValueSpacing: 2,
            barDatasetSpacing: 1,
            tooltipTemplate: function (valueObj) {
                return $filter('date')(valueObj.label, 'shortDate')
            }
        };
```

My chart currently looks like this:

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Clbh.png)

Answer (score -1):

From docs:

```
new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: data,
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            display: false
        }]
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I have tried that but doesn't seem to work with the angularjs chartjs directive https://gist.github.com/AndreasHeiberg/9837868

Comment: Try something along the lines of Chart.defaults.bar.scales.xAxes.display = false.